# Mongoose eachAsync with async function = memory leak?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am not sure if it's a bug in mongoose or if I am doing something wrong. Once I start using async functions when iterating on a cursor with `eachAsync` I experience memory leaks (quickly goes up to 4gb and then crashes). After trying some things I noticed that this wouldn't happen if I don't use an async function as callback.

**No Memory leak:**

```
const playerCursor: QueryCursor<IPlayerProfileModel> = PlayerProfile.find({}, projection).lean().cursor();
    await playerCursor.eachAsync(
      (profile: IPlayerProfileModel) => {
        return;
      },
      { parallel: 50 }
    );
```

**Memory leak:**

```
const playerCursor: QueryCursor<IPlayerProfileModel> = PlayerProfile.find({}, projection).lean().cursor();
    await playerCursor.eachAsync(
      async (profile: IPlayerProfileModel) => {
        return;
      },
      { parallel: 50 }
    );
```

Obviously above code doesn't make any sense but I need to perform an asynchronous operation within the function.

**Question:**

What is causing the memory leak / how can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this a memory leak, but memory exhaustion. A leak is when some process completes and continues on, but some bit of memory hasn't been released, and so becomes orphaned and unusable. Then over time memory can run out if these add up. In your case there is no underlying memory deallocation bug, but an explosion in parallel processing which just needs a lot of memory. Perhaps it would work fine it you had enough RAM to finish the balloon.

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with how [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) work.

Quoting the documentation:

> When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved
>   with the returned value.

Meaning, values returned by `async` functions will be automatically wrapped into a `Promise`.

In your first code sample, your code returns `undefined` whereas in the second code sample your code returns `Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

> What is causing the memory leak?

I didn't take a look at `mongoose` code but [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#services-cursor-eachAsync-js) states:

> If fn returns a promise, will wait for the promise to resolve before iterating on to the next one.

Since your first example does not return a `Promise`, I am thinking your callback is executed on each result all at once rather than sequentially.

> How can I avoid it?

I'd recommend using `async/wait` as you used it on your second code sample.

After taking a look at the code (looking for an answer myself), if provided with a callback that doesn't return a promise `eachAsync` will run the callback as many times as fast as possible as it can.

[This line](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.13.8/lib/services/cursor/eachAsync.js#L29) is where your callback is executed. The next line checks whether it's a `Promise` and if it's not then execute **right away** `callback` which effectively calls your `eachAsync` callback on the next result. If your callback has any sort of async operation but returns right away then you end up with thousands and thousands of async operations running all at once.

On top of that, you set the option `parallel` to `100` so [it executes `eachAsync` callback one hundred times in parallel](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.13.8/lib/services/cursor/eachAsync.js#L64).

This isn't a bug on `mongoose` because there are cases where this behavior is wanted and it does provide with a sequential processing using `Promise`. The documentation should mention the caveat of using a callback which doesn't return a `Promise`.

To go a little further, [`express` uses `next` on middleware callbacks](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for the purpose of sequencing them.